# How to use BETWEEN or <,> operators in DATETIME field

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a table called data which has a field called `'datetime'`. The field is set as varchar. The values of this field looks like below:

```
2014-12-04.2300,
2014-12-04.2200,
2014-12-04.1600
```

This is `(date.24hr time)` format. How can I select all records between two dates like `2014-12-02 and 2014-12-05?`

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN 2014-12-02.0000 AND 2014-12-05.2300
```

But it doesn't work and returns empty. Any idea how?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried quoting the values and removing the `.0000`, i.e. `'2014-12-02'`

Comment: Would it be possible to convert those columns to the native `datetime` type? Doing that will save you future headaches.

Comment: i have tried with removing 0000s. I can't convert it to the usual datetime type. I know it's headache :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the values. Right now they are arithmetical expressions. MySQL interprets `2014-12-02.0000` as `2014 minus 12 minus 2.0000` and it is not wrong at all.

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN '2014-12-02.0000' AND '2014-12-05.2300'
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select records between 2 dates then try this query

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN date('2014-12-02') AND date('2014-12-05')
```

in case of varchar field use below query

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE date(left(`datetime`, 10)) BETWEEN date('2014-12-02') AND date('2014-12-05')
```

Comment: I would also cast `datetime` into date, I think it should be done too. maybe `date(left(`datetime`, 10))`

Comment: it is a varchar, field, so I think he's obliged to do that.

Comment: They are still wrong because, as I said in my answer, `2014-12-02` is exactly `2000`.